# How to create a straight line from start and end vertices of a line using Qgis?

Tags: qgis, vector, line, geoprocessing, vertices

I want to create a straight line from two vertices of a line which are not straight, but I should be getting a straight line joining the start and end vertices of this curve line.

[image]

I want to attain the green line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several options to do this:

1. [Create a new line-layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-new-vector-layers), toggle editing, [activate snapping](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=snapping#setting-the-snapping-tolerance-and-search-radius) and draw a line by snapping to start- and endpoint.
2. Use this expression with Geometry generator or Geometry by expression ([see here how](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)):
   `make_line (start_point ($geometry),end_point ($geometry))`
3. [Create a virtual layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) with this query:

   ```
   select make_line (end_point (l.geometry), start_point (l.geometry))
   from line as l
   ```

Comment: please ... don't answer so quick ... ;-p

Comment: Sorry - you were to post the same answer...?

Comment: Thanks for the competition! was really helpful

Comment: You're welcome. From the three options, I prefer the 2nd one, using expressions. It seems to be the most straightforward as you don't have to create a new layer manually.

Comment: Yeah, took the one with the expression only, so quick and effective results are coming.